# “sehr wundervoll” — idiomatic?

Tags: adjective, idiomaticity

To me, the combination of *sehr* and *wundervoll* sounds a bit odd/clumsy and I’m wondering:

- Am I alone?
- If not, what could be the reason for it being odd?
- Are there other adjectives that can’t be combined with *sehr*?

Comment: By the way: If I would ever feel the need to augment *wundervoll,* I would use *ausgesprochen wundervoll.*

Comment: You should also note, that the word "wundervoll" is much rarer used in German Language than the word "wonderful" in an english context. To give your verbal expression a more German sound, better use »großartig«, »herrlich«, »hervorragend« or »traumhaft«. Even »wunderbar« is much better than »wundervoll«. In some phrases even more replacements are possible: »to get away *wonderfully*« = »*glänzend* miteinander auskommen«.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- No, you are not alone.
- The word in itself expresses a degree of excitement that cannot be increased further.
- Many. You find some quickly by browsing the synonyms of [wundervoll](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wundervoll): *ausgezeichnet, einmalig, sensationell, exzellent...* Go on with mathematical terms like *unendlich, geradzahlig, dreieckig* and finally discover the linguistic term [Absolutadjektiv](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolutadjektiv).